# Unable to turn off 'Mouse Keys enabled on sign-in' setting in Windows Ease of Access

Tags: windows-10, keyboard, ease-of-access

In `Control Panel\All Control Panel Items\Ease of Access Center\Change sign-in settings`, the After Sign-in setting for Mouse Keys will not persist when I try to uncheck it. I can go to that page, uncheck the box, and hit apply/Ok, then immediately return to the sign-in settings page and find it checked again.

My issue is similar to [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/1163124/windows-10-mouse-keys-settings-will-not-apply) and [this one for Windows 7 where the user wants to turn on Mouse Keys](https://www.sevenforums.com/general-discussion/334483-mousekeys-settings-wont-save.html), but specifically relates to the sign-in setting and **disabling** Mouse Keys. Attempting to turn off the after sign-in setting is sufficient to disable mouse keys for the current session, but it will always be back on after I log out & back in.

I have tried:

- Pressing Apply then OK
- Making sure Mouse Keys is turned off in the normal settings before changing the sign-in setting
- Searching the internet to try to find a similar problem. The closest I found was the Windows 7 problem mentioned above.
- Looked through start-up services to see if something looking like accessibility was on that shouldn't be.

If this is a Windows bug, how might I create a scheduled task or something to disable mouse keys on sign in, after the Ease of Access Mouse Keys setting I don't want has been applied?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Doing a system repair also did not work. I ended up needing to create a new user profile for myself and move all my files over, which finally solved the problem.

Answer (score 1):

I had this same problem in Windows 10 and for months it drove me crazy.  I tried the Windows 7 solutions, as well, and they didn't work.  I tried changing the HKCU/Accessibility/MouseKeys flag in registry but it wouldn't stick. What finally fixed it was this..  I had to turn off **Use mouse keys when Num Lock is on** first.  Then switch off **Use numeric keypad to move mouse around the screen**.  Now it doesn't revert to the on position when I reboot.

Answer (score 1):

Still a problem in Jan 2020 on Win 10 Pro x64 version 1909.
Turning off MouseKeys in sign-in-settings didn't stick. PITA.

Had to do a minor regedit but this worked for me:

- Rebooted.
- Went to "Control Panel"\"Ease of Access"\"Ease of Access Centre" and into "Make the keyboard easier to use".
- Unchecked "Turn on Mouse Keys", then Apply, OK.
- Ran `regedit` and went to key:

  > Computer\HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Accessibility\Configuration

  This is apparently a comma-delimited list with MS and/or 3rd-party accessibility apps listed.
  As only mousekeys was in mine, I just edited the key to be blank (did *not* delete key).
- Back at "Ease of Access Centre" clicked (left, near top) "Change sign-in settings"...
  Sure enough the annoying checkbox for mousekeys in the "After sign-in" column was gone.

Rebooted and still clear :-)

Answer (score -1):

Right click on ease of programs/accessories/access/ease of access center
then properties
then on security tab - deny permissions

Answer (score -1):

i had the same problem as all of the above ..and it had nothing to do with the ease of access centre .   turned out i had accidentally pressed the Scroll Lock button ...  just press it again and num pad is back to normal ....  i cant believe no one else has thought of this ...lol

Comment: Welcome to Super User! Before answering an old question having an accepted answer (look for green ✓) as well as other answers **please read all answers** and ensure your answer adds something new or is otherwise helpful in relation to them. Here is a guide on [answer]. There is also [tour] for the site tour, and [help] for the help center.